# r program side-by-side boxplots

Tags: r

I have three different boxplots,

```
k1<-boxplot(decreased$Group.1)

k2<-boxplot(unchanged$Group.1)

k3<-boxplot(created$Group.1)
```

Is there any way I can make side-by-side boxplot with it or do I have to combine the columns for table together and use ~ to find out side by side?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen but you will need to play with the `xlim`, `ylim`, `at` and `add` arguments.

See this example:

```
boxplot(1:10, xlim=c(1,6), ylim=c(0,20), at=1.5)
boxplot(2:10, add=TRUE, at=3.5)
boxplot(3:20, add=TRUE, at=5.5)
```

[image]

So, you need to add the x-limits and y-limits on the first plot along with the location of where to plot the first barplot (specified by `at`). Then consecutive barplots need the location (i.e. again `at`) and also the `add=TRUE` argument.